# forloop python with list naming

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, foreach

Hi I'm trying to perform a forloop

```
    concatted  score       date status  apple  banana  orange
0  apple_bana  0.500 2010-02-20   high   True   False   False
1       apple  0.400 2010-02-10   high   True   False   False
2      banana  0.530 2010-01-12   high  False    True   False
3        kiwi  0.532 2010-03-03    low  False   False   False
4        cake  0.634 2010-03-05    low  False   False   False 

df = df.drop(['banana', 'orange'], axis=1)

df['apple_count'] = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D')])
df["apple_high"] = df.groupby('date')['status'].transform(lambda x: (x=='high').sum())
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(df['date'], df['apple_count'])
fig.suptitle('Apple Graph', fontsize=20)
```

This code works for apple. But how could I do a forloop:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
for fruit in fruits:
```

The loop needs to:

1. first only keep rows if that respective fruit's column =True
2. perform the 2 calculations, naming the columns and graph with respective `fruit' as the prefix.

Comment: Use string concatenation ?, the only problem is that you need to work on temp copy of your raw dataframe (you shouldn't update df)

Comment: `['apple', 'banana', 'orange'].remove('apple')` gives you `['banana', 'orange']` which you can use in `drop()`. The same with `fruits.remove(fruit)` - but you will have to do this with copy of `fruits` to keep it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can duplicate `fruits` and `remove(fruit)`

```
all_fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']

for fruit in all_fruits:
    drop_fruits = all_fruits.copy()
    drop_fruits.remove(fruit)

    print('to drop:', drop_fruits)
```

Result:

```
to drop: ['banana', 'orange']
to drop: ['apple', 'orange']
to drop: ['apple', 'banana']
```

---

Or you cans use `set() - set()`

```
all_fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']

for fruit in all_fruits:
    drop_fruits = list(set(all_fruits) - set( [fruit] ))

    print('to drop:', drop_fruits)
```

---

But all this would need to duplicate `df` before `droping`. Maybe better is to use

```
new_df = df[ ['concatted', 'score', 'date', 'status', fruit] ]
```

and work with this `new_df`

```
... = new_df.groupby(...)
```

---

And later

```
df[ fruit + '_count' ] = ...
df[ fruit + '_high' ] = ...
```

or

```
df[ '{}_count'.format(fruit) ] = ...
df[ '{}_high'.format(fruit) ] = ...
```

or using `f-string`

```
df[ f'{fruit}_count' ] = ...
df[ f'{fruit}_high' ] = ...
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry: in the loop, how could I first only keep rows if that fruit's column == True ? (and then I i'd use the f-string approach to perform the calculations) I've updated the question, apologies again.

Comment: do you mean `df[ df['apple'] == True ]` or more universal `df[ df[ fruit ] == True ]` ?

Comment: More generally, I think please. So for each fruit in the list, keep only rows that has a true under that fruit's column. I think this would need to create a new dataframe for each fruit somehow and then merge only the 2 calculation columns created for each fruit on the original df.

Comment: but you got more generally `selected_rows = df[ df[ fruit ] == True ]` which you have to run in `for`-loop to get only rows for selected fruit

Comment: BTW: i wouldn't use columns `apple`,  `banana`, `orange` but one column `fruit_type` with values  `apple`,  `banana`, `orange`, and the same with result - one column `count`, high` for all results. This way you can have many fruit types without adding new columns.

Comment: Thank you! And that's a good point. How could I duplicate the rows, though? Each row can cite multiple fruits. I need to do analysis on each fruit (even if there are duplicate observations between fruits)

Comment: to duplicate row you can append row at the end `df = df.append(df.iloc[row_number])` but it may need to reset index `df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: I kept the format for now. But I'm unsure how to avoid performing the same calculation for all fruit:```df[ df[ fruit] == True ]``` and then   ```df[f'{fruit}_daily'] = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D')])```

Comment: maybe `selected_rows = df[ df[ fruit] == True ]` and then `selected_rows.groupby(...)`